# How do I fix this process in Tableau?

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau 10.1 and with it I'm working with some big .xlsx (one of the sheets has more than 12,000 rows).
Almost every action that I do on this program with these files can take from 5 minutes to 990 minutes!!!! (as you can see on the picture).
Some other actions take like 2 hours or 14 minutes each and I don't know why.
I will try to get to the official forums of Tableau to try to get help from a developer.
I think one of my best options is to let the program use more process from my PC (it has 16.384 GB of RAM, with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz).

Does anyone have another tip??? [Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iykuO.png)

Comment: Have you tried tableau extracts?

Comment: 12,000 rows in Excel is negligible and on its own shouldn't take more than a few seconds. Do you have complicated calculated fields? What does your data source look like?

Comment: How many *columns* in your Excel file and how big (in MB) is the file?

Answer (score 1):

Use data extracts. They create a high performance columnar data source out of your excel data.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/extracting_data.html